# Adding Wcf Service does not allow namespace access

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

I have created a wcf service called ServiceIRE. I add a service reference to my project by right clicking on th eproject in solution explorer and clicking add Service Reference. I am able to discover my created service and click ok after specifying the namespace ServiceReference1. All files seem to be generated properly.

I then go to the codebehind and try to add a using statment "using ServiceReference1;". This is unrecognized by the file even though the namespace apparently exists in the same project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

ServiceIRE.cs

```
namespace FakeIREServiceLibrary
{

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class ServiceIRE : IServiceIRE
{
    public string GetData()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        var randomNumber = rnd.Next(10);
        Random rndID = new Random();
        var randomNumberID = rnd.Next(10000);
        Thread.Sleep(randomNumber*1000);
        return string.Format("Thread # {0} returned in {1} nanoseconds", randomNumberID, rnd.Next());
    }


}
```

IServiceIRE.cs

```
namespace FakeIREServiceLibrary
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IServiceIRE
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData();

    }
}
```

Page.aspx.cs

```
using ServiceReference1; //THIS IS NOT RECOGNIZED
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Is your `using` statement in a Web Site (File->New Web Site)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the default namespace for your project?

I believe you have to do something like "using DefaultNamespaceForProject.ServiceReference1;"

You can find the default namespace by right clicking your project.. clicking Properties, and then going to the Application tab.

Comment: This is a web porject and I am unable to find the default namespace for the project. I see "Property Pages" and "Properties Window" but that is all. Is there another way to find this?

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: Btw, I think by default the "default namespace" is the name of the project.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the namespace of the service client generated by Visual Studio by looking at the Reference.cs file within the Service Reference after you show all files for that project. The default is [Project namespace].[Namespace specified].

It's possible that it did NOT generate the file because of an error. That may be the behavior you're seeing.

I would also encourage you to [NOT use Add Service Reference](http://brandonzeider.me/2011/microsoft-net/visual-studio-add-service-reference/), but to instead [use a ChannelFactory](http://brandonzeider.me/2011/net-faq/using-channelfactory/) or [build a reusable service client](http://brandonzeider.me/2011/microsoft-net/building-a-reusable-service-client/).

Comment: +1 for recommending ChannelFactory over adding service references.

Comment: @Tim - thanks. Service references are great when you're just trying to learn the technology, but that's about it IMO.